# Is the JavaScript syntax the same for all browsers?

Tags: web-development, javascript

As for interacting with the DOM, different browsers will offer methods -and results- that are different between them to some or other extent.

But how about JavaScript itself? Do all browsers (or platforms e.g. Adobe Reader) implement the same syntax and behavior?

Aspects that particularly worry me are function/object handling and arithmetical operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The JavaScript standards committee updates JavaScript annually. Browser Support Varies. Tooling is available to help.

Javascript is defined by the [ECMA-262 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/), which is updated anually. Every revision has added *some* new syntax. All browsers since IE5 support a common subset of syntax in the same way, it's only a question of if they support new syntax options or not. However, since syntax extensions can be as small as [Allowing trailing commas in parameter lists](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-trailing-function-commas), it's not always obvious which options you are using. [Here's a list of the changes](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_new-javascript-features.html) since they went to annual updates.

It is common practice (in 2021,) to include a build step for your JavaScript that replaces newer syntax with older syntax so that code can be run in older browsers that are not updated. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), [Browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist), and [@babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) make it easy to support a configurable set of browsers. (As long as you're still developing your site!)

Comment: I don't know about non-browser environments. Except Flash, where actionscript is based on an abandoned version that never became a standard (ES4).

Comment: Yeah MainMa's answer somehow suggests this too, printed myself a copy of the 262 standard and all. All the DOM stuff is missing though, obviously. It's great to know that the version 5 retrofits. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this answer is a decade old and is quite outdated nowadays. There's since been a lot of new syntax added to JavaScript. And trailing commas definitely is no longer the only syntax differences to be aware of. There's arrow functions, class syntax, let/const keyword, default arguments, etc whose browser support varies depending on how long you want to support old browsers. Though there's also been lots of new tools like Babel and shims that helps masks these differences.

Comment: @LieRyan: Good catch. How's this update for a modern approach?

Comment: @SeanMcMillan Much better.

Answer (score 5):

[Different browsers](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/) support different [versions of JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions), and different versions of JavaScript have changes in their syntax. So no, the syntax is not the same, except if you stick with the version old enough to be supported in most browsers.

For example, you can see some [cool syntax](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips) which, for some, is available in JavaScript 1.8, released in June 2008 and incompatible with FF2 and, as usual, all releases of IE except 9.

Answer (score 3):

The current JavaScript version is 1.8.5. JavaScript has evolved over many stages. So different browsers not only differ in their DOM models, but also in syntax. An overview for browsers is given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions). So you should be careful when using advanced features.

Answer (score 3):

> But how about JavaScript itself? Do all browsers (or platforms e.g.
>   Adobe Reader) implement the same syntax and behavior?

No. Every browsers support a different version of JavaScript. Not only that, event different versions of the same browsers have different JavaScript capabilities.

This is way there are now numerous ways of ensuring cross-browsers compatibilities for the same JavaScript task, usually requiring feature-detection and then acting based on it.

A good practice to ensure compatibility is to always check for feature detection rather than version detection for browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few gotchas to do with basic Javascript syntax that Internet Explorer will choke on (it might be better in IE9, but IE 6/7/8 had horrible problems).

Things like a trailing comma after the last element in an array (think something like `[a, b, c,]`, every browser will handle it fine *except* IE.

There are quite a few more along that vein as well.

Comment: Nice contribution, cheers Karpie. Googling a bit I found this SO answer along those lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235987/ie7-8-javascript-gotchas